# Xcode 8.1 Install

Tags: macos, xcode8

I downloaded Xcode_8.1.xip at work in order to install it on my mac however it only extracts (as expected) but it is never installed when I go into the store it still wants me to install it.

Please assist me, I have no knowledge of installing xip, when it still was dmg file it was a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got the manual download. You double-click the xip, it extracts. Then you move the extracted Xcode app to `/Applications` (cmd-shift-A on desktop, or in a Finder window). It won't auto-update through app store this way, though. If you want auto-updates, delete `/Applications/Xcode.app` and reinstall through App store.

Comment: Will try that, I cannot install it from my useless internet it is too slow so I had to download the xip file